# Git-Ignore in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, git

I am using X-Code 10 as a C IDE. I am doing a group project and we must use GitLab to share the code. To work in Xcode there are a lot of files to make Xcode work, but none that I need to share with my partners who are using their own IDE and who just need the .c files we are working on. How do I make Git not upload ALL files and just the .c?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to handle the excludes for a git project.  There is the `.gitignore` file where you can create rules for what files should be excluded from your project.  This file will be tracked by git, so you and your teammates will be sharing this file.

For your own personal excludes, you can put them into the `.git/info/exclude` file.  This will not be tracked by git and will affect only your own local repository.  This is a good place put rules that are specific to your own workflow.